# createnamedpipe not working in win 7 .how to change security attributes using c#

Tags: c#, windows

createnamedpipe not working in win 7 .how to change security attributes using c#

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public int nLength;
            public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            public int bInheritHandle;
        }

public bool CreatePipe()
        {
            // Make a named pipe in message mode

```
        IntPtr securityDescriptorPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        int securityDescriptorSize = 0;
        bool result = ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(
            LOW_INTEGRITY_SSL_SACL, SDDL_REVISION_1, out securityDescriptorPtr, out securityDescriptorSize);
        if (!result)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES securityAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        securityAttributes.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(securityAttributes);
        securityAttributes.bInheritHandle = 1;
        securityAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor = securityDescriptorPtr;

        _handle = CreateNamedPipe(_pipeName,
            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
            PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT,
            PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
            PIPE_SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE,
            PIPE_SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE,
            NMPWAIT_WAIT_FOREVER,
            securityAttributes);
        // Make sure we got a good one
        if (_handle.IsInvalid)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Could not create the pipe (" + _pipeName + ") - os returned " +
                Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

due to security attributes it gives exception.why is so????
i got error in 
 bool result = ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(
                LOW_INTEGRITY_SSL_SACL, SDDL_REVISION_1, out securityDescriptorPtr, out securityDescriptorSize);
line which is The specified datatype is invalid(win32 exception)

Comment: you should provide more detail, for example what exception is thrown, why don't you use the System.IO.Pipes classes NamedPipeServerStream and NamedPipeClientStream, do they work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with native node (and the access issues may be the same in managed code), there is some guidance for Vista [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowssecurity/thread/9bd7c2de-ec7f-4141-980a-260689d02745) (a long thread but should have everything you need).  Also managed code methodology.  Not sure if this applies identically to Windows 7 but it might get you started.

In summary:

> It seems that there is no way to
>   modify the permissions of a named pipe
>   after it has been created. I tried and
>   it always either simply doesn't work
>   or returns ACCESS_DENIED. So, I had to
>   specify both the DACL and SACL up
>   front when creating the pipe.
>
> The DACL code was pasted above in an
>   earlier thread and the SACL can be
>   created as follows:
>
> 1. Create a new using InitializeAcl()
> 2. Initialize a new SID specifying 'SECURITY_MANDATORY_LOW_RID'
> 3. Call AddMandatoryAce() to add the SID to the ACL
> 4. Call SetSecurityDescriptorSacl() to add the ACL to the security descriptor